# HomeAsUpIndicator Custom View

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm looking at adding a custom view for the `HomeAsUpIndicator` whenever there are new message. I want to bring attention to the hamburger icon when there are new messages, and then use the default hamburger icon when there aren't new messages.

I have two functions to display custom icon and display default, but I want to use a custom `View`.

```
protected void setCustomIcon() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_hamburger);
    mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    });
}

protected void setDefaultIcon() {
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
}
```

Is there a way to use a custom `View` instead of a `resId` or a `drawable`?

Comment: did you try using a layerlist drawable. One solution could be to use the regular drawable, and when you need the notification one use the layer list one. Not a great solution if you want more customization though.

Comment: The `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` overload that takes a `Drawable` allows for quite a bit of flexibility, but if you really want to swap out a custom `View` in your toggle, you'd wanna just make a custom toggle from the start. Are you trying to do some sort of overlay on the hamburger-arrow image? Or just some kind of static replacement `View`?